# Display Loading gif after response.redirect VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, response.redirect

I tried to find a similar topic but I could not solve it with the topics I found, that's why I am creating this article now.

I want to display an animated Loading gif after a response.redirect in the Page behind.

Looks like this:

```
If IsPostBack Then

   Dim EventTarget() As String

   EventTarget = Request("__EVENTTARGET").Split("$")


   If EventTarget(2) = "btnWeiter" Then

      Response.Redirect("voucherordercontrol.aspx", False)

   End If

End If
```

The next page's data is loaded from a SQL Server in a while loop with a `DataReader` and finally displayed in a `GridView`.

I want to display this gif, until the data is fully loaded and the `GridView` is displayed. I tried so many things, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display an animated Loading gif after a response.redirect in
>   the Page behind.

**Answer is you cannot.** It is too late to display loading icon, once you reach to sever code. You cannot do that in **voucherordercontrol.aspx** either, because voucherordercontrol.aspx takes long time to load as you said.

Only way you can achieve is to display the loading icon before you post back to server. For example, display loading icon as soon as button is clicked at client-side.